# Legacy approach to Spring 3.1 MVC restful initalization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with a legacy Spring MVC restful oriented application (that for legal reasons cannot be upgrade easily) but I can't find a way to set initialization variables.  These are static settings and properties that I can't set inside the web.xml (E.g. I could have used the servlet context variables).

If I were using Spring 4.x and Servlet spec 3, I could use the 'WebApplicationInitializer' class but I can't use that with Spring 3.x and Servlet Spec 2.5. We are not using J2EE spec 3 either.  What class or approaches could I use for initializing the web application.  I was trying to avoid just using pure static variables.

The goal is to set variables before any of the Spring beans are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the initialization of some static initialization value you could put it in a properties file and load it with  and then use it in your bean for configure it, you also could think of use a @PostCostrunct method in withs you could initialize your variable and then use it.

The case of  is very simple but for the next solution you could do it.

```
class Config{

    private Map prop;


 @PostCostruct
public void init() {
    prop = load properties from file and put in the map;
}   


// getter of prop
}
```

**However if you use Spring > 3.1 the my personal advice was use the Enviroment abstraction simply you could @Autoviewd an istance of Enviroment class and use system enviroment variable for the your configuration, I consider that this last idea will be the most secure for your application.**

I hope that this can help you